# Convert base64 string to pdf

Tags: android, kotlin, pdf

I'm trying to convert from a base64 string to pdf and then open that pdf file in the app.

My problem is that i don't know how to create the file with the path after I decode the base64 stringm, and then use the path to open the file with pdf reader

Until now I have this code:

```
  private fun pdfConverter(file: DtoSymptomPdf?) {
    val dwldsPath: File = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath + "/" + file?.filename + ".pdf")
    val pdfAsBytes: ByteArray = android.util.Base64.decode(file?.file, 0)
    val os = FileOutputStream(dwldsPath, false)
    os.write(pdfAsBytes)
    os.flush()
    os.close()
}
```

Comment: You cannot write to the root of external storage on modern Android devices. Write to `getExternalFilesDir()` (a method on `Context`), then use `FileProvider` to get a `Uri` to use with `ACTION_VIEW`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the below code hope this will work for you. Apart from the code, you need to create `file_provider_paths.xml` and add `<provider/>` tag into your `AndroidManifest.xml`

**`file_provider_paths.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

Create `file_provider_paths.xml` and put the above code into `file_provider_paths.xml` file

**`AndroidManifest.xml`**

```
    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        tools:replace="android:authorities">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_provider_paths"
            tools:replace="android:resource" />
    </provider>
```

Put the `<provider/>` tag into your `AndroidManifest.xml`

**`MainActivity.kt`**

```
fun generatePDFFromBase64(base64: String, fileName: String) {
    try {
        val decodedBytes: ByteArray = Base64.decode(base64, Base64.DEFAULT)
        val fos = FileOutputStream(getFilePath(fileName))
        fos.write(decodedBytes)
        fos.flush()
        fos.close()

        openDownloadedPDF(fileName)
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        Log.e("TAG", "Faild to generate pdf from base64: ${e.localizedMessage}")
    }
}

private fun openDownloadedPDF(fileName: String) {
    val file = File(getFilePath(fileName))

    if (file.exists()) {
        val fileProviderAuthority = "{APPLICATION_ID}.fileprovider"
        val path: Uri = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, fileProviderAuthority, file)
        } else {
            Uri.fromFile(file)
        }

        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf")
        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
        val chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open with")
        try {
            startActivity(chooserIntent)
        } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
            Log.e("TAG", "Failed to open PDF  ${e.localizedMessage}")
        }
    }
}

fun getFilePath(filename: String): String {
    val file =
        File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).path)
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdirs()
    }
    return file.absolutePath.toString() + "/" + filename + ".pdf"
}
```

Comment: This works, but I could do the same if I store it in the internal storage with getFilesDir()?

Comment: I'm not sure about that but `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)` works for me.Anyway it will give you internal storage download folder path. You can try once using `getFilesDir()`

Comment: What is mFileProviderAuthority?

Comment: Basically it's fileProviderAuthority only there was some variable name mistake. It's update now