# Pdf intent not showing file

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fileprovider

I'm trying to display in the pdf intent of android an file using his Uri, but it seems that I always get an blank pdf and don't know why, can someone give me some advice why.

Code:

```
 private fun pdfConverter(pdfFile: DtoSymptomCheckerPdf?) {
    val documentsPath = File(context?.filesDir, "documents")
    if(!documentsPath.exists()){
        documentsPath.mkdir()
    }
    val file = File(documentsPath, pdfFile?.filename)
    val pdfAsBytes: ByteArray = android.util.Base64.decode(pdfFile?.file, 0)
    val os = FileOutputStream(file,false)
    os.write(pdfAsBytes)
    os.flush()
    os.close()
    println("EL CONTENT: " + file.length())
    val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(App.applicationContext,
        BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file)
    val pdfIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
    pdfIntent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf")
    pdfIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
    try {
        startActivity(pdfIntent)
    } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Can't read pdf file", 
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
     }
   }
```

Comment: Use Android Studio's Device File Explorer or `adb pull` to copy your PDF to your development machine. Can you open the PDF in a desktop PDF viewer? If the answer is no, then the PDF is corrupt.

Comment: @CommonsWaren You are right I can't open it even from my machine. But I don't know what it's the problem or how can I figure it out. Any advice?

Comment: It could be that `pdfFile` does not have what you expect. Or, it could be something in writing out the content, though off the cuff that part seems OK.

Comment: try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/69759486/9633290, have answered for both for generating pdf from base64 string & open file.